# Linking online accounts with OTB real names in database

Tags: database, chessbase, scid

I have just started to get back into chess from a long time away. I have joined my local club and started to compete. I have been playing around with SCID vs PC and wonder if you can link your opponent's online names under their real names, since I have been playing some people online and OTB. I am also considering investing in Chessbase, so if this is a feature available on there or any other chess database please let me know.

Comment: Isn't anonymity the whole point of online names? ;-)

Comment: Yes but if they tell you there name. I have joined my local club and know a number of the members online names.

Comment: depends on the site. I collect my chess.com games and for each game i use an api call to try and collect the players name if they have it. I also store that data so i dont need to call each and every game i have with that player. So yes it can be done...but only if the other party is willing to have their name known.

Comment: Thanks @David i haded thought of using and API

Answer (score 1):

The feature you are describing is not built into either SCID or Chessbase natively. You can quickly rename players in a database, or alternatively automate through scripting.

I use the following API endpoints for chess.com to collect that information.
https://www.chess.com/news/view/published-data-api#pubapi-endpoint-player